# Export AWS AMI as a master for bare metal, non-virtualized installations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, clone, iso

I work for a small start up that needs to deploy lots of desktop computers to end users with Ubuntu and Open CV installed.

To save money on hardware, I'd like to use AWS to mock up our base deployment environment ( Ubuntu plus Open CV and several other packages ). Then, I'd like to export the AMI of that environment and use it to mass produce hard drives with the same OS and software setup.

Is this a common thing to do? Specifically, use Amazon Machine Images as "golden master records", as it were, to clone the EC2 instance's operating system and software to several, real world, non-cloud, non-virtualized machines?

If so, what are the steps, where do I find them?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to export most AMIs. However if you import a VM into AWS, then make changes, you can use [VM Import/Export](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html) to export it.

So your first step is to create a VM locally, then import it into AWS, customise it, then export it.

I'm not sure why doing this in AWS is easier than doing it on-premise though.